# Why are the paintComponents being called but not seen?

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, jcomponent

I have a GridLayout of Cells that each extends JComponent. 
The GridLayout manages a Board class that extends JPanel and the Board object/panel is added to the main panel with two other panels.

Here's the Cell Class:

```
public class Cell extends JComponent{

    private int row;
    private int col;

    private int rowHeight;
    private int colWidth;

    private boolean active = false;

    private Color color;

    public Cell(int row, int col, Color color) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;

        this.color = color;
    }

    public Cell(int row, int col, int rowHeight, int colWidth, Color color) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;

        this.rowHeight = rowHeight;
        this.colWidth = colWidth;

        this.color = color;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        paintSquare(g);
    }

    private void paintSquare(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRoundRect(
            (int) (col * colWidth),
            (int) (row * rowHeight),
            (int) (rowHeight),
            (int) (colWidth),
            10,
            10);

    }

    public int getCol()
    {
        return col;
    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        return row;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Here's the Board Class:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

    public Cell[][] gameBoard;

    public final int GAME_ROWS;
    public final int GAME_COLUMNS;

    public int rowHeight;
    public int columnWidth;

    public Color selectedColor;

    public Board(int GAME_ROWS, int GAME_COLUMNS) {
        this.GAME_COLUMNS = GAME_COLUMNS;
        this.GAME_ROWS = GAME_ROWS;

        calculateDimensions();

        createGameBoard();

        setUpBoardPanel();
    }

    private void calculateDimensions() {
        rowHeight = (int) this.getHeight() / GAME_ROWS;
        columnWidth = (int) this.getWidth() / GAME_COLUMNS;
    }

    private void createGameBoard() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int cellColor;
        gameBoard = new Cell[GAME_ROWS][GAME_COLUMNS];
        for (int row = 0; row < GAME_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GAME_COLUMNS; col++) {
                cellColor = random.nextInt(Properties.COLORS.length);
                Cell newCell = new Cell(row, col, rowHeight, 
                    columnWidth,Properties.COLORS[cellColor]);
                gameBoard[row][col] = newCell;
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpBoardPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(GAME_ROWS, GAME_COLUMNS));
        setPreferredSize(Properties.BOARD_TABLE_SIZE);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 10, 0, 0));
        setBackground(Properties.BACKGROUND_COLOR);

        addBoardPanelComponents();
    }

    private void addBoardPanelComponents() {
        for(int r = 0; r < GAME_ROWS; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < GAME_COLUMNS; c++) {
                add(gameBoard[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything on the main panel is showing up perfectly, and I can see that the Board panel was added because I when I change its background it shows up as it's set.

I've looked through a bunch of tutorials and am calling super right so I'm not sure how the components could be added and called correctly and just not show up.

To see the full program code you can go to my [github](https://github.com/scohen40/ColorFlood), but the relevant code is above. TIA!

Comment: When overwriting paintComponent to draw on a component, you should do it on a JPanel, not on a JComponent

Comment: @Snowy_1803 Can you explain further?

Comment: Your Cell class should extend JPanel, it’s not a new component type. Developers shouldn’t overwrite painting on any other component than JPanel and JLabel.

Comment: @Snowy_1803 Where are you getting that information from? Extending `JComponent` should be fine. Even though it's common to find code snippets online where people are extending `JPanel` for custom painting, it doesn't really make sense because it breaks the Liskov substitution principle. (`JPanel` is supposed to be a container for other components.) Overriding `paintComponent` on a `JLabel` frankly sounds like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: My first thought is that this is a layout issue. Since you're using a grid layout, I'd recommend overriding `getPreferredSize` on the `Cell` class, and then avoid using any explicit sizing methods like `setPreferredSize`.

Comment: My suspicion is, the x/y position been calculated is outside the visible range of the component

Comment: @Radiodef Can you please explain what you mean by overriding getPreferredSize?

Comment: @Radiodef "instanceof JPanel" is often used in UI classes to check for custom painting, as it’s UI doesn’t paint anything but the background, whereas a JComponent can have its UI set to any other UI than a PanelUI. All the official tutorials uses JPanel for custom painting. The JLabel’s paintComponent shouldn’t be overwritten, but it’s paintBorder can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "core" issue is, you don't understand how the coordinate space of a component works.

The `x`/`y` position of component is relative to its parent.  The top/left corner of any component/container is always `0x0`.

So when you do something like this...

```
g.fillRoundRect(
                (int) (col * colWidth),
                (int) (row * rowHeight),
                (int) (rowHeight),
                (int) (colWidth),
                10,
                10);
```

You're saying, fill a rect which starts at `col * width` x `row * rowHeight` relative to the top left corner of the component itself (which is always `0x0`)

What you should be doing is something more like this...

```
g.fillRoundRect(
                0,
                0,
                getWidth() - 1,
                getHeight() - 1,
                10,
                10);
```

This will fill the entire visible area of the component.

But why use `getWidth` and `getHeight`.  Well, in this context, this ensures that the entire visible area of the component is filled, but how do you affect the size of the component?

The preferred way is to override the `getPreferredSize` method of the component and return the "preferred" size (all things been equal).

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(colWidth, rowHeight);
}
```

This provides a hint to the parent layout manager about how the component would "like" to be laid out.

Another issue is...

```
    private void calculateDimensions() {
        rowHeight = (int) this.getHeight() / GAME_ROWS;
        columnWidth = (int) this.getWidth() / GAME_COLUMNS;
    }
```

This is pointless, because until the component has undergone a layout pass, it's size is `0x0`, so, basically you're saying the `rowHeight` and `columnWidth` should be `0x0` :/

Honestly, best to just rid of it.  If you need to, seed a known value to the `Cell` directly

## Runnable example...

[image: Blobs]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Board(10, 10));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Board extends JPanel {

        public Cell[][] gameBoard;

        public final int GAME_ROWS;
        public final int GAME_COLUMNS;

        public int rowHeight = 50;
        public int columnWidth = 50;

        public Color selectedColor;

        public Board(int GAME_ROWS, int GAME_COLUMNS) {
            this.GAME_COLUMNS = GAME_COLUMNS;
            this.GAME_ROWS = GAME_ROWS;

            createGameBoard();

            setUpBoardPanel();
        }

        private void createGameBoard() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int cellColor;
            Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW};
            gameBoard = new Cell[GAME_ROWS][GAME_COLUMNS];
            for (int row = 0; row < GAME_ROWS; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < GAME_COLUMNS; col++) {
                    cellColor = random.nextInt(colors.length);
                    Cell newCell = new Cell(row, col, rowHeight,
                                    columnWidth, colors[cellColor]);
                    gameBoard[row][col] = newCell;
                }
            }
        }

        private void setUpBoardPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(GAME_ROWS, GAME_COLUMNS));
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 10, 0, 0));
            setBackground(Color.RED);

            addBoardPanelComponents();
        }

        private void addBoardPanelComponents() {
            for (int r = 0; r < GAME_ROWS; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < GAME_COLUMNS; c++) {
                    add(gameBoard[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Cell extends JComponent {

        private int row;
        private int col;

        private int rowHeight;
        private int colWidth;

        private boolean active = false;

        private Color color;

        public Cell(int row, int col, int rowHeight, int colWidth, Color color) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;

            this.rowHeight = rowHeight;
            this.colWidth = colWidth;

            this.color = color;
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(colWidth, rowHeight);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            paintSquare(g);
        }

        private void paintSquare(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRoundRect(
                            0,
                            0,
                            getWidth() - 1,
                            getHeight() - 1,
                            10,
                            10);

        }

        public int getCol() {
            return col;
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }

}
```